# how to upgrade NGINX to 1.18.0 stable version

Tags: nginx

I want to upgrade nginx version from 1.18.0. to 1.18.0 stable. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

but version is 1.18.0

Comment: Run it with Docker?

Comment: Mainline is the active development branch where the latest features and bug fixes get added. It is denoted by an odd number in the second part of the version number, for example 1.19.0. It is not a stable version

Comment: Look at their site. https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-18-1-19-released/